# Blender Animation Render Missing

Tags: rendering

When I render my animation, I see the render frame by frame perfectly in the viewport, but when I access the PNG or JPEG files upon completion, they are either all black or completely transparent without the mesh.

This is my first time rendering an animation in blender so it can be a very simple fix.

Thanks!

Background:
Using HDR as lighting - checked transparent under "Film" so it doesn't render.

Baked the rigid body animation into keyframes.

I know it's ideal to render as PNG or JPEG, but h.264 isn't even an option, idk if it's only rendering first frame over and over?

Comment: h.264 is available, it is inside the FFmpeg/Encoding. Did you do anything in the compositor editor? It is inside the node editor.

Comment: Have you checked how the camera is set up and made sure everything you want has render visibility?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up